# Mutation Observer only triggering on Parent Element

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I'm trying to use a MutationObserver to watch for removed nodes in an application library, but it appears that when a parent is removed (or replaced), it doesn't trigger the callback for all of the child elements.

```html
<button class="RemoveListButton">Remove List</button>
<div class="Container">
  <ul class="ShoppingList">
    <li class="Item">Pasta</li>
    <li class="Item">Chips</li>
    <li class="Item">Salsa</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
const removeWatcher = new MutationObserver(mutationList => {
    const removedNodes = mutationList.flatMap(m => [...m.removedNodes])
    console.log('Removing', removedNodes)
})

const container = document.querySelector('.Container')
removeWatcher.observe(container, { subtree: true, childList: true })

/* additional javascript to remove elements on click */
```

See JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eq4ahsvc/3/

In the example, when I remove an individual list item (by clicking on it), I see in the console that the element was removed and seen by the Mutation Observer.

However, when I remove the entire list, the Mutation Observer callback is only triggered for the parent, and not the individual child elements.

Is there a way to configure this behavior? Ideally every element would trigger the MutationObserver callback, such that when removing the list, I see the trigger for removing the list, and the trigger for removing each of the child elements.

Comment: if an element with 1000 children is removed like el.remove(), its 1000 children won't be reported by MutationObserver, it's the intended behavior for performance. You can enumerate the element yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child elements are *not* removed from their parent, so there's no remove event to observe. See:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const li = ul.children[0];
ul.remove();

console.log(li.parentElement);
```

```html
<button class="RemoveListButton">Remove List</button>
<div class="Container">
  <ul class="ShoppingList">
    <li class="Item">Pasta</li>
    <li class="Item">Chips</li>
    <li class="Item">Salsa</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `<li>`s still have a parent element of the `.ShoppingList`, because the `.ShoppingList` was removed from its container, but the individual `<li>`s were not removed from the `.ShoppingList`.

If you wanted to see events for each removed `<li>`, you'd have to iterate over and remove them explicitly in addition to removing the `.ShoppingList`:

```js
const removeWatcher = new MutationObserver(mutationList => {
  const removedNodes = mutationList.flatMap(m => [...m.removedNodes])
  console.log('Removing', removedNodes)
})

const container = document.querySelector('.Container')
removeWatcher.observe(container, { subtree: true, childList: true })

const button = document.querySelector('.RemoveListButton')
button.onclick = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.ShoppingList > li').forEach(li => li.remove());
 document.querySelector('.ShoppingList').remove()
}

const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.Item')
listItems.forEach(item => item.onclick = () => {
 event.target.remove()
})
```

```html
<button class="RemoveListButton">Remove List</button>
<div class="Container">
  <ul class="ShoppingList">
    <li class="Item">Pasta</li>
    <li class="Item">Chips</li>
    <li class="Item">Salsa</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For what you want, either do that, or recursively flatten all children of every item in the `removedNodes` array inside the observer callback.

Comment: oh wow, that makes sense... It didn't occur to me that the elements were still attached to their parent, so they technically weren't being removed... okay, this answer makes sense. Thank you!

I'll probably go with the recursively flattening all the children and triggering removals there.